# Adding view below another recently animated view

Tags: android, animation

I have edit view that I animated from the middle of the screen to the top using object animator:

```
animators.add(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(ev, "y", 0));
```

On animationEnd I try to add another view below it:

```
        EditText ev2= new EditText(getActivity());
        ev2.setText("Test");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ev.getId()); // first view id (ev) 
        params2.leftMargin = 107;
        groupView.addView(ev2, params2);
```

This will be added below to the original position of the first edit view. How can I add other view exactly below the view after animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use LinearLayout with vertical orientation.